# GenericForeignKey Inline in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.11

I have a multiple product models:

```
class ProductModelA(..

class ProductModelB(..

class ProductModelC(..
```

Model `Order` and `SubOrder` which stores information about quantity. So every `Order` can have multiple `SubOrders` which stores tuple `product` and `quantity`.

```
class Order(..

class SubOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('orders.Order',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='suborders')
    product = GenericForeignKey()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='suborders')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(..)
```

I'm trying to make user friendly admin interface with inline `suborder`. Choosing from existing `product`s would be enough (alongside with amount field) but can't figure out how to do that.

I tried:

```
class SubOrderInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = SubOrder


@admin.register(Order)
class OAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SubOrderInline]
```

But it doesn't work:

[image]

I don't want to choose from `Order` objects, I want to choose from either `ProductModelA`,`ProductModelB` or `ProductModelC` objects. Is there a built in way?

Comment: Have you tried using normal `TabularInline` instead of the generic one? GenericInline should be used when you have the generic relation between the main model (the one that you're editing) and inline model.

Comment: Yes, but it is not userfriendly, you have to choose content type and then raw id. I would rather something like 3 dropdowns.

Comment: You can provide your own form widget for that. If you want to have something better, look at [models inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) and [Django polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Unclear of what you're asking. Seems like using inlines is a bad idea. Perhaps you want to have 3 FKs or an M2M

Comment: As mentioned above but to make it more clear to you: you cannot use a GenericInline, as the relation between Order and SubOrder is a regular ForeignKey - so use TabularInline. What you are looking for is a way to make a Genericforeignkey Field userfriendly. I have used a module called Django Generic Smart Selects for that in the past but I am not sure how well that is maintained.